# Understanding Deadlock graph of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I need some little help to understand why a specific deadlock is happening on a specific table of my database. I know a very little of deadlocks, specially deadlocks on a same table.

Could you give some help with this deadlock? I'm not searching a specific solution, I just only want to know why this deadlock is happening:

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process4aa5b88">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process4aa5b88" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:6535" 
            waittime="4912" ownerId="260658" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:10.040" 
            XDES="0x8006bb70" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="2804" status="suspended" spid="221" sbid="0" ecid="5" 
            priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" 
            lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ANP-APP" 
            hostpid="6728" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="260658" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" 
            clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="2" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7f3e035aa74a68d308785ac6386d1ee4b1f924e">  
                    UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>      </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process4a8b288" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:6535" 
            waittime="6287" ownerId="260658" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:10.040" 
            XDES="0xbf9597b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="7" kpid="6952" status="suspended" spid="221" sbid="0" ecid="7" 
            priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" 
            lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ANP-APP" 
            hostpid="6728" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="260658" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" 
            clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="2" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7f3e035aa74a68d308785ac6386d1ee4b1f924e">  
                    UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>      </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process463d948" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:6503" 
            waittime="4912" ownerId="260657" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:10.040" 
            XDES="0xb4595850" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2060" status="suspended" spid="219" sbid="0" ecid="3" 
            priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" 
            lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ANP-APP" 
            hostpid="6728" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="260657" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" 
            clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="2" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7f3e035aa74a68d308785ac6386d1ee4b1f924e">  
                    UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>      </inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process449ebc8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 14:1:6503" 
            waittime="6287" ownerId="260657" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:10.040" 
            XDES="0x80007a70" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="6936" status="suspended" spid="219" sbid="0" ecid="5" 
            priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" 
            lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ANP-APP" 
            hostpid="6728" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="260657" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" 
            clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="2" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7f3e035aa74a68d308785ac6386d1ee4b1f924e">  
                    UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>      </inputbuf>
            </process>

            <process id="process4a8b048" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="4905" schedulerid="7" kpid="6324" 
            status="suspended" spid="219" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" 
            lastbatchstarted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-10T09:35:09.993" 
            clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="ANP-APP" hostpid="6728" loginname="sa" 
            isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="260657" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" 
            clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="2" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7f3e035aa74a68d308785ac6386d1ee4b1f924e">  
                    UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>   UPDATE ic_seguimiento_contenedor   SET nave_id = M.id_interno, nave_nombre=M.campo2   FROM mantenedor_general M   WHERE ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_id = 0   AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.estado_cod&lt;20 AND M.id_empresa=ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.id_empresa=105 AND M.mantenedor=&apos;mant_nave&apos;   AND ltrim(rtrim(M.campo1))=ltrim(rtrim(ic_seguimiento_contenedor.nave_cod)) AND ic_seguimiento_contenedor.key_negocio =&apos;53E010566725403&apos;    </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6535" dbid="14" objectname="icomexvi_dys.dbo.ic_seguimiento_contenedor" id="lock95e1e800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594108248064">
                <owner-list/>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process4aa5b88" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6535" dbid="14" objectname="icomexvi_dys.dbo.ic_seguimiento_contenedor" id="lock95e1e800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594108248064">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process4a8b048" mode="U"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process4a8b288" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6503" dbid="14" objectname="icomexvi_dys.dbo.ic_seguimiento_contenedor" id="lock96c23080" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594108248064">
                <owner-list/>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process463d948" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6503" dbid="14" objectname="icomexvi_dys.dbo.ic_seguimiento_contenedor" id="lock96c23080" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594108248064">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process4aa5b88" mode="U"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process449ebc8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </pagelock>
            <exchangeEvent id="Pipec6a2eac0" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="4">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process463d948"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process4a8b048"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </exchangeEvent>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

I very appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you have [multiple processes trying to update many rows on the same page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tDB1B.png). Getting to the bottom of it will depend on understanding what other statements are involved in the outer transactions. I can't see the other statements in the batch and therefore what might cause the deadlock (alone this should just be blocking). You might try a few things, such as changing the app so that it updates fewer rows at a time (maybe you can avoid the page locks through a better index), and/or eliminating parallelism for this statement (using `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`)

Comment: I have had a database server with the overhead of replication where the reporting sp's would be the most likely victims. My solution, not mission critical data, was to start using WITH (NOLOCK) on the reporting procs.

Comment: thanks for your information and suggest @AaronBertrand. That "sql sentry plan explorer" program seems very powerful to identify and learn about my problem. I will give a try. Even if i could improve query performance, first i want to know what is happening. As another question, ¿there is a posibility to "lock" all the table, not the pages, on every query? I know that's not the best option, but i just want to know if exist. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

- These are the processes: `process4aa5b88`, `process4a8b288`, `process463d948`, `process449ebc8` and `process4a8b048`.

  - Page 6535 is owned by `process4a8b048` and waited by `process4aa5b88` and `process4a8b288`.
  - Page 6503 is owned by `process4aa5b88` and waited by `process449ebc8` and `process463d948`.
  - Parallel exchange pipe `Pipec6a2eac0` is owned by `process463d948` and waited by `process4a8b048`.

The  deadlock cycle is this:

1. `process4aa5b88` waits page 6535, owned by `process4a8b048`
2. `process4a8b048` waits exchange pipe owned by `process463d948`
3. `process463d948` waits page 6503 owned by `process4aa5b88`

QED a cycle in the wait list => deadlock

Presence of parallelism and page granularity locks during scan is a clear indication of a missing index. Review the WHERE clause, make sure you have SARGable arguments. Read [Index Design Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179560%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and all linked chapters.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Remus Rusanu, thanks for the explanation, i did not saw parallelism problems on previous deadlocks that i had, so i was a little confused. I will keep getting information about this deadlock (¿or block?) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but if you want to become aware of deadlocks in real-time then you can create an alert that calls a sp that sends an email to sql operators. It pretty straightforward.

1. Create a table to hold deadlock events.

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeadlockEvents](
           [AlertTime] [datetime] NULL,
           [DeadlockGraph] [xml] NULL
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
2. Create a SQL Agent Job with the following exec sql as step 1.

   DECLARE @xml XML;
   SELECT @xml=N'$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(TextData)))'

   INSERT INTO ILMDW.dbo.DeadlockEvents
                                 (AlertTime, DeadlockGraph)
                   VALUES (getdate(), N'$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(WMI(TextData)))')

   EXEC ILMDW.dbo.MAINTENANCE_Deadlock_Graph @xml
3. Create a SQL Server Management/Alert configured as follows.

[image]

[image]

4. Then have the sp send emails to you or othere when a deadlock occurs -->

   ALTER PROC [dbo].[MAINTENANCE_Deadlock_Graph]  @xml XML
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @body VARCHAR(MAX)
   CREATE TABLE #victim_list(process_id VARCHAR(100))
   CREATE TABLE #processdetails
   (
    id                 VARCHAR(100),
    taskpriority       VARCHAR(100),
    logused            VARCHAR(100),
    waitresource       VARCHAR(100),
    waittime           VARCHAR(100),
    ownerId            VARCHAR(100),
    transactionname    VARCHAR(100),
    lasttranstarted    VARCHAR(100),
    XDES               VARCHAR(100),
    lockMode           VARCHAR(100),
    schedulerid        VARCHAR(100),
    kpid               VARCHAR(100),
    status             VARCHAR(100),
    spid               VARCHAR(100),
    sbid               VARCHAR(100),
    ecid               VARCHAR(100),
    priority           VARCHAR(100),
    trancount          VARCHAR(100),
    lastbatchstarted   VARCHAR(100),
    lastbatchcompleted VARCHAR(100),
    clientapp          VARCHAR(100),
    hostname           VARCHAR(100),
    hostpid            VARCHAR(100),
    loginname          VARCHAR(100),
    isolationlevel     VARCHAR(100),
    xactid             VARCHAR(100),
    currentdb          VARCHAR(100),
    lockTimeout        VARCHAR(100),
    clientoption1      VARCHAR(100),
    clientoption2      VARCHAR(100)
   )
   CREATE TABLE #frame_details
   (
    id                 VARCHAR(100),
    procname           VARCHAR(100),
    line               VARCHAR(100),
    stmtstart          VARCHAR(100),
    sqlhandle          VARCHAR(100)
   )
   CREATE TABLE #frame_values
   (
    id                 VARCHAR(100),
    frame              VARCHAR(max)
   )
   CREATE TABLE #input_buffer
   (
    id                 VARCHAR(100),
    inputbuf           VARCHAR(max)
   )
   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_keylock
   (
    hobtid             VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    objectname         VARCHAR(100),
    indexname          VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    associatedObjectId VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_objectlock
   (
    lockpartition      VARCHAR(100),
    objid              VARCHAR(100),
    subresource        VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    objectname         VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    associatedObjectId VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_databaselock
   (
    subresource        VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    dbname             VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_exchangeEvent
   (
    id                 VARCHAR(100),
    waitType           VARCHAR(100),
    nodeId             VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_metadatalock
   (
    subresource        VARCHAR(100),
    classid            VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    dbname             VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #resource_details_pagelock
   (
    fileid             VARCHAR(100),
    pageid             VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    dbname             VARCHAR(100),
    objectname         VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    associatedObjectId VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   create table #resource_details_ridlock
   (
    pageid             VARCHAR(100),
    dbid               VARCHAR(100),
    dbname             VARCHAR(100),
    objectname         VARCHAR(100),
    lock_id            VARCHAR(100),
    mode               VARCHAR(100),
    associatedObjectId VARCHAR(100),
    owner_id           VARCHAR(100),
    owner_mode         VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_id          VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_mode        VARCHAR(100),
    waiter_requestType VARCHAR(100)
   )

   INSERT INTO #victim_list
           SELECT dl.n.value('@victim','VARCHAR(100)')
           FROM @xml.nodes('TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #processdetails
        select dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS id,
        dl.n.value('@taskpriority[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS taskpriority,
        dl.n.value('@logused[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS logused,
        dl.n.value('@waitresource[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS waitresource,
        dl.n.value('@waittime[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS waittime,
        dl.n.value('@ownerId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS ownerId,
        dl.n.value('@transactionname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS transactionname,
        dl.n.value('@lasttranstarted[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lasttranstarted,
        dl.n.value('@XDES[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS XDES,
        dl.n.value('@lockMode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lockMode,
        dl.n.value('@schedulerid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS schedulerid,
        dl.n.value('@kpid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS kpid,
        dl.n.value('@status[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS status,
        dl.n.value('@spid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS spid,
        dl.n.value('@sbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS sbid,
        dl.n.value('@ecid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS ecid,
        dl.n.value('@priority[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS priority,
        dl.n.value('@trancount[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS trancount,
        dl.n.value('@lastbatchstarted[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lastbatchstarted,
        dl.n.value('@lastbatchcompleted[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lastbatchcompleted,
        dl.n.value('@clientapp[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS clientapp,
        dl.n.value('@hostname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS hostname,
        dl.n.value('@hostpid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS hostpid,
        dl.n.value('@loginname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS loginname,
        dl.n.value('@isolationlevel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS isolationlevel,
        dl.n.value('@xactid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS xactid,
        dl.n.value('@currentdb[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS currentdb,
        dl.n.value('@lockTimeout[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lockTimeout,
        dl.n.value('@clientoption1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS clientoption1,
        dl.n.value('@clientoption2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS clientoption2
        FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #frame_details
        SELECT dl.n.value('../../@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS id,
        dl.n.value('@procname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS procname,
        dl.n.value('@line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS line,
        dl.n.value('@stmtstart[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS stmtstart,
        dl.n.value('@sqlhandle[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS sqlhandle
        FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process/executionStack/frame') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #frame_values
       SELECT dl.n.value('../@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS id,
       dl.n.value('frame[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS frame
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process/executionStack') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #input_buffer
       SELECT dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS id,
       dl.n.value('inputbuf[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS inputbuf
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/process-list/process') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_keylock
        SELECT dl.n.value('@hobtid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS hobtid,
        dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
        dl.n.value('@objectname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS objectname,
        dl.n.value('@indexname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS indexname,
        dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
        dl.n.value('@associatedObjectId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS associatedObjectId,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
        FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/keylock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_objectlock
       SELECT dl.n.value('@lockpartition[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lockpartition,
        dl.n.value('@objid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS objid,
        dl.n.value('@subresource[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS subresource,
        dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
        dl.n.value('@objectname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS objectname,
        dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
        dl.n.value('@associatedObjectId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS associatedObjectId,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/objectlock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_databaselock
        SELECT dl.n.value('@subresource[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS subresource,
        dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
        db_name(dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)')) AS dbname,
        dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/databaselock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_exchangeEvent
        SELECT dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@waitType[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS waitType,
        dl.n.value('@nodeId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS nodeId,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
        FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/exchangeEvent') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_metadatalock
       SELECT dl.n.value('@subresource[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS subresource,
       dl.n.value('@classid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS classid,
       dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
       db_name(dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)')) AS dbname,
       dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
       dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
       dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
       dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
       dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
       dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
       dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/metadatalock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_pagelock
        SELECT dl.n.value('@fileid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS fileid,
        dl.n.value('@pageid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS pageid,
        dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
        db_name(dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)')) AS dbname,
        dl.n.value('@objectname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS objectname,
        dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
        dl.n.value('@associatedObjectId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS associatedObjectId,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
        FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/pagelock') dl(n)

   INSERT INTO #resource_details_ridlock
        SELECT dl.n.value('@pageid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS pageid,
        dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS dbid,
        db_name(dl.n.value('@dbid[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)')) AS dbname,
        dl.n.value('@objectname[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS objectname,
        dl.n.value('@id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS lock_id,
        dl.n.value('@mode[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS mode,
        dl.n.value('@associatedObjectId[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)','VARCHAR(100)') AS associatedObjectId,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_id,
        dl.n.value('(owner-list/owner)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS owner_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@id','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_id,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@mode','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_mode,
        dl.n.value('(waiter-list/waiter)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOcE.png)/@requestType','VARCHAR(100)') AS waiter_requestType
       FROM @xml.nodes('//TextData/deadlock-list/deadlock/resource-list/ridlock') dl(n)

   SELECT @body='Process id(Victim)'
   SELECT @body=@body+''+isnull(process_id,'')+'' from #victim_list
   SELECT @body=@body+'
   '

   SELECT @body=@body+'Process Details:
         
          Process id
          DB_Name
          procname
          waittime
          lockMode
          trancount
          clientapp
          hostname
          loginname
          frame
          inputbuf
         '

   SELECT DISTINCT isnull(pd.id,'') as [id],
    isnull(db_name(pd.currentdb),'') as [currentdb],
    isnull(fd.procname,'') as [procname],
    isnull(pd.waittime,'') as [waittime],
    isnull(pd.lockMode,'') as [lockMode],
    isnull(pd.trancount,'') as [trancount],
    isnull(pd.clientapp,'') as [clientapp],
    isnull(pd.hostname,'') as [hostname],
    isnull(pd.loginname,'') as [loginname],
    isnull(fv.frame,'') as [frame],
    isnull(ib.inputbuf,'') as [inputbuf]
   into #p_details_temp
   from #processdetails pd
   left join #frame_details fd on pd.id=fd.id
   left join #frame_values fv on fd.id=fv.id
   left join #input_buffer ib on fv.id=ib.id

   SELECT @body=@body+
     ''+id+''+
     ''+currentdb+''+
     ''+procname+''+
     ''+waittime+''+
     ''+lockMode+''+
     ''+trancount+''+
     ''+clientapp+''+
     ''+hostname+''+
     ''+loginname+''+
     ''+frame+''+
     ''+inputbuf+''
   FROM #p_details_temp
   SELECT @body=@body+'
   '

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #resource_details_keylock) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'Keylock:
    '+
        'hobtid,'+
        'dbid,'+
        'objectname,'+
        'indexname,'+
        'lock_id,'+
        'mode,'+
        'associatedObjectId,'+
        'owner_id,'+
        'owner_mode,'+
        'waiter_id,'+
        'waiter_mode,'+
        'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       select @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(hobtid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(objectname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(indexname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(lock_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(associatedObjectId,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
        from #resource_details_keylock
       select @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #resource_details_objectlock) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'ObjectLock:
    '+
        'lockpartition,'+
        'objid,'+
        'subresource,'+
        'dbid,'+
        'objectname,'+
        'lock_id,'+
        'mode,'+
        'associatedObjectId,'+
        'owner_id,'+
        'owner_mode,'+
        'waiter_id,'+
        'waiter_mode,'+
        'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       SELECT @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(lockpartition,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(objid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(subresource,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(objectname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(lock_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(associatedObjectId,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
       FROM #resource_details_objectlock
       SELECT @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #resource_details_databaselock) 
   BEGIN

   ```
   SELECT @body=@body+'DatabaseLock:<br><table border="1"> <tr>'+   
    '<th>subresource,</th>'+  
    '<th>dbid,</th>'+  
    '<th>dbname,</th>'+  
    '<th>lock_id,</th>'+  
    '<th>mode,</th>'+  
    '<th>owner_id,</th>'+  
    '<th>owner_mode,</th>'+  
    '<th>waiter_id,</th>'+  
    '<th>waiter_mode,</th>'+  
    '<th>waiter_requestType,</th>'+  
    '</tr>'  
   SELECT @body=@body+'<tr>'+   
    '<td>'+isnull(subresource,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(dbid,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(dbname,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(lock_id,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(mode,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(owner_id,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(owner_mode,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(waiter_id,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+'</td>'+  
    '<td>'+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+'</td>'+  
    '</tr>'  
   from #resource_details_databaselock   
   select @body=@body+'</table><br/><br/>'
   ```

   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #resource_details_exchangeEvent) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'ExchangeEvent:
    '+
        'lock_id,'+
        'waitType,'+
        'nodeId,'+
        'owner_id,'+
        'owner_mode,'+
        'waiter_id,'+
        'waiter_mode,'+
        'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       SELECT @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waitType,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(nodeId,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
       FROM #resource_details_exchangeEvent
       SELECT @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM #resource_details_metadatalock) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'MetadataLock:
    '+
       'subresource,'+
       'classid,'+
       'dbid,'+
       'dbname,'+
       'lock_id,'+
       'mode,'+
       'owner_id,'+
       'owner_mode,'+
       'waiter_id,'+
       'waiter_mode,'+
       'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       SELECT @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(subresource,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(classid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(lock_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
       FROM #resource_details_metadatalock
       SELECT @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #resource_details_pagelock) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'PageLock:
    '+
        'fileid,'+
        'pageid,'+
        'dbid,'+
        'dbname,'+
        'objectname,'+
        'lock_id,'+
        'mode,'+
        'associatedObjectId,'+
        'owner_id,'+
        'owner_mode,'+
        'waiter_id,'+
        'waiter_mode,'+
        'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       SELECT @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(fileid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(pageid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(objectname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(lock_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(associatedObjectId,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
       FROM #resource_details_pagelock
       SELECT @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM #resource_details_ridlock) 
   BEGIN
       SELECT @body=@body+'RidLock:
    '+
        'pageid,'+
        'dbid,'+
        'dbname,'+
        'objectname,'+
        'lock_id,'+
        'mode,'+
        'associatedObjectId,'+
        'owner_id,'+
        'owner_mode,'+
        'waiter_id,'+
        'waiter_mode,'+
        'waiter_requestType,'+
        ''
       SELECT @body=@body+''+
        ''+isnull(pageid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbid,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(dbname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(objectname,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(lock_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(associatedObjectId,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(owner_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_id,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_mode,'')+''+
        ''+isnull(waiter_requestType,'')+''+
        ''
       FROM #resource_details_ridlock
       SELECT @body=@body+'
   '
   END

   SELECT @body=@body+'Original XML'+
        replace( replace( convert(VARCHAR(MAX),@xml),  '<','<' ),  '>','>' )+
       ''

   DECLARE @email_distribution_list VARCHAR(1024)
   SELECT @email_distribution_list = 'ross@ilearn.com;brad@ilearn.com;kenny@ilearn.com;spenser@ilearn.com'

   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
       @profile_name = 'SQL NOTIFICATIONS',
       @recipients=@email_distribution_list,
       @body = @body,
       @body_format='HTML',
       @subject = 'Alert! DeadLock Occurred On Server',
       @importance = 'High' ;

   DROP TABLE #victim_list
   DROP TABLE #processdetails
   DROP TABLE #frame_details
   DROP TABLE #frame_values
   DROP TABLE #input_buffer
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_databaselock
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_exchangeEvent
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_keylock
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_metadatalock
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_objectlock
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_pagelock
   DROP TABLE #resource_details_ridlock
   DROP TABLE #p_details_temp

   END

Comment: Thanks @lrb for your help, i didn't work with alerts before, so im a little newbie about that. Anyway i will give a try. Thanks!